# VBA Insert Picture Dynamically In Cell Based On Cell Value and do nothing if the cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba, image, dynamic, range

I have a statement with Image Dynamically In Cell (fom I11 to I19)
I usually only use 2 or 3 lines, so the other 7-8 are empty. My macro command works fine in cells that are filled, but for empty cells it also inserts an image that says "The linked image cannot be displayed". I would like VBA not to insert an image if cell D11 to D19 is empty. Also, to run the command I have to click on the developer tab and macros, can this be automated (column D has data validation)?. Thank you

```
Sub Insert_Multiple_Images()

Set Image_Names = Range("D11:D19")
Image_Location = "C:\Image"
Image_Format = ".png"

Set Cell_Reference = Range("I11:I19")

For i = 1 To Image_Names.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Image_Names.Columns.Count
        Set Image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Image_Location + "\" + Image_Names.Cells(i, j) + Image_Format)
        Image.Top = Cell_Reference.Cells(i, j).Top
        Image.Left = Cell_Reference.Cells(i, j).Left
        Image.ShapeRange.Height = 45
        Image.ShapeRange.Width = 75
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can this be automated (column D has data validation)?"? To make it automatically working if a cell value in the range "D11:D19" is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next solution. You did not answer the clarifications question, so it automatically run if any cell in range "D11:D19" is change. The code checks if a picture exists on the corresponding cell ("I & modified cell row), it is deleted. If after modification the cell is empty, the code does not do anything:

Please, copy the next code in the sheet you need to process code module (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Image_Names As Range

    Set Image_Names = Range("D11:D19")
    If Not Intersect(Image_Names, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim Image_Location As String, Image_Format As String, i As Long, Image As Object
        Image_Location = "C:\Image"
        Image_Format = ".png"
        
        If Target.value <> "" Then 'if the changed cell is not empty:
                'check if picture exists:
                If Dir(Image_Location & "\" & Target.value & Image_Format) <> "" Then
                    'if picture already exists, delete it:
                    deletePicture Target.Offset(, 5).Address
                    
                    Set Image = Me.Pictures.Insert(Image_Location & "\" & Target.value & Image_Format)
                    Image.top = Target.Offset(, 5).top: Image.left = Target.Offset(, 5).left
                    
                    Image.ShapeRange.height = 45: Image.ShapeRange.width = 75
                Else
                    MsgBox "No picture exists on path """ & Image_Location & "\" & Target.value & Image_Format
                End If
        Else
            'if picture already exists, delete it:
            deletePicture Target.Offset(, 5).Address
       End if
    End If
End Sub

Sub deletePicture(rngAddr As String)
    Dim sh As Shape
    
    For Each sh In Me.Shapes
        If sh.Type = 11 Then 'to process only the necessary pictures...
            If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = rngAddr Then sh.Delete: Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

The code can process all the range as your code does, but since nothing has been changed in the rest of the range, it will only be Excel wasting resources, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens (doesn't show images at all)

Comment: @Filipal This cannot be possible... Where and how did you copy the above code? If copied as it should, you maybe have events disabled.  Create a simple sub with a single code line `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it. In fact, did you use your path? The code used to have one where I made tests... Please, use the adapted one, using your path.

Comment: I removed my code and pasted yours in Modules - Module 1

Comment: @Filipal You did it wrong! I clearly explained where to paste it... **Please, copy the next code in the sheet you need to process code module (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`)**... Please, copy there **the updated code**. It also checks if the entered picture name exists on the respective path...

Comment: @Filipal Still alive? Did you copy the code in the **sheet code module**? If  not, do you understand how and where to copy it? If copied there, didn't it work as it should?

Comment: I'm a beginner in VBA, I haven't learned the basic concepts yet :-( I removed the Macro and copied the code to the right place but  now i got an error for If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = rngAddr Then (in yellow)

Comment: @Filipal No problem. But saying something about an error, without specifying **without saying what error** is not of much help... So, what error?

Comment: Run-time error !1004!: Application-defined or object-defined error. When I select Debug in "Sub deletePicture", for "For Each sh In Me.Shapes" yellow is "If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = rngAddr Then"

Comment: @Filipal  Did you copy the code **exactly** as it is? Is there the line `Dim sh As Shape`? If yes, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed ? Without seeing what happens on your computer is difficult to understand...

Comment: I have AnyDask  address 404 545 357

Comment: @Filipal OK. I will try connecting now. Please, open a Notepad window to communicate on it... And do not move the cursor after I will be connected, until we will set some rules (on Notepad).

Comment: @Filipal please delete your comment above. I will adapt the code with what I did in your computer. Adapted the code...

Answer (score 0):

Could try using dynamic range for last row used in column D and column I and match the 2 ranges.

dim lRowD as integer

'find last row used and  in worksheet 1 column D (column 4)'
lRowD = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

'Update these lines'
Set Image_Names = Range("D11:D" & lRowD)
Set Cell_Reference = Range("I11:I" & lRowD)

Also, can go to insert -> shapes and right click menu on a shape and assign a macro rather than going to developer tab.